# Operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector2' and 'Vector3'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my AI to avoid an obstacle but I'm having errors. How to fix it?

```
public Transform[] waypoints;

public float speed = 2.0f;

public float obstacleRange = 1.0f;

private int currentWaypoint = 0;

void Update()
{
    if (currentWaypoint >= waypoints.Length)
    {
        return;
    }

    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[currentWaypoint].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[currentWaypoint].position) < 0.1f)
    {
        currentWaypoint++;
    }

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, (waypoints[currentWaypoint].position - transform.position).normalized, obstacleRange);
    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        float angle = Random.Range(-45, 45);
        Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.position = (Vector3)(hit.point + q * (hit.point - (Vector2)transform.position));
    }

}
```

I expected my AI to avoid obstacles when moving.

Comment: Seems like the operation you are trying to perform is not (directly) implemented but types could be cast to the other and both have it defined on themselves, so it's unclear which way to go. (I am just _guessing_. Haven't worked with those types. But that's what I'd investigate for.)

Answer (score 0):

The operation [`Quaternion * Vector3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) does only exist for `Vector3` - not for `Vector2` - and it returns a `Vector3` again.

=> Even though you tried hard to stay with `Vector2` the moment you used the `q * x` the `x` is implicitly converted from `Vector2` to a `Vector3` and the result is also a `Vector3`

=> You then have a

```
hit.point + aVector3
```

which is where the error comes from.

---

You will have to make sure to cast again

```
transform.position = hit.point + (Vector2)(q * (hit.point - (Vector2)transform.position));
```